# On combining $n$ and $n^2$ into one number

Tags: number-theory, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $T_n$ formed by combining $n$ and $n^2$ into one number.
ie. (A053061)
$$T_n=\{11,24,39,416,525,636,749 \cdots\}$$
It is easy to see
$$T_n= 10^{\lceil 2 \log_{10}(n) \rceil } n+ n^2$$

I looked at the sequence closely trying to find if there are any perfect squares in the sequence but wasn't able to  upto $n=100$. 
I also was able to prove that if $n^{th}$ term is a perfect square then :

1) $n \equiv 8 \text{ or }  0 (\text{ mod } 9)$

2)In the case where $n=9m$ , m is not a square free number.

But I am unable to attack the question

> Do there exist  any perfect square in the sequence?

Comment: There is something wrong with the formula you gave for $T_{n}$. As it stands, $T_{1} = 2$. On the on the hand, if by $\log n$ you are actually referring to the base $10$ logarithm of $n$ then $T_{n}$ is nothing but $n^{3}+n^{2}.$

Comment: @J.H.S. sorry my mistake ..now it looks better

Comment: Not sure why people are voting to close (unless maybe it was before the post was corrected). The general sequence $B^{\lceil 2\log_B(n)\rceil}\cdot n+n^2$ seems like a perfectly reasonable sequence to study, and asking if it contains squares is also a reasonable question. And I'm pretty sure it's not going to be easy to determine, say, if the sequence contains finitely many or infinitely many squares.

Comment: $a^2=b^2+10^n b$, so $a^2-(b+10^n/2)^2=10^{2n}/4$. So solutions come from factorizations of $10^n/4$. We are looking for solutions with $ b$ between $10^{n-1}$ and $10^n-1$. This corresponds to factors in a certain range.

Comment: We can remove any extraneous factors of $10$ until $a+b$ and $a-b$ are $2\cdot5^{2n}$ and $2^{2n-3}$. Then clearly neither the sum nor the difference is in the correct range.  They are much too big. So I think this is impossible.

Comment: @WillSawin: I would certainly upvote an official answer that fleshed out the outline you've given!

Comment: I expect votes to close are because the user claims to be 15 years old, and the sequence under discussion, http://oeis.org/A053061, has as its sole reference: *Felice Russo, A set of new Smarandache functions, sequences and conjectures in number theory, American Research Press 2000*

Comment: @BenjaminDickman: Why discriminate on age? Perhaps it might be suitable for math.stackexchange, but it is seemingly a non-trivial question.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson It is not about the age: http://planetmath.org/florentinsmarandache

Comment: @PerAlexandersson I was not able to fetch the reference at OEIS and I am an high school student from India . I am just curious about this sequence as I did not find it any where else. _(ed ajf)_

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no squares in this sequence.

Elements of this sequence are of the form $b^2+10^n b$ for $10^{n-1} \leq b^2 < 10^n$. So we are looking for a special solution to the equation $a^2 =b^2+ 10^n b$. This is an easy Diophantine equation to solve: We have $a^2 - (b+10^n/2)^2 = - 10^{2n}/4$, or

$(a+b+10^n/2)(a-b-10^n/2) = -10^{2n}/4$

The two factors on the left side have the same parity. Clearly we may assume $n>1$, so these factors both must be even. If those factors are both multiples of $20$, then $a$ and $b$ are both multiples of $10$, and we may divide $a$ and $b$ by $10$ and subtract $1$ from $n$ without changing the equation. However, it does modify the inequality. So each factor is either a power of $2$ or $2$ times a power of $5$, hence the two factors must be $2 \cdot 5^{2n}$ and $2^{2n-3}$. This gives:

$a+b+10^n/2 = 2\cdot 5^{2n}$

$a-b-10^n/2 = 2^{2n-3}$

$b= 5^{2n} - 2^{2n-4} -10^n/2$

For $n=2$, we get $575$, but $575^2>100$. For higher $n$, it's even worse: $b^2$ is much greater than $10^n$. Similarly, multiplying $a$ and $b$ by $10$ and adding $1$ to $n$ also makes $b^2$ larger, relative to $10^n$. So there are no solutions.

Comment: can this method be extended tp prove there exist no perfect $k$ powers by combining $n$ and $n^k$ ?

Comment: @ShivamPatel - I don't immediately see how, because the equation is more complicated, but there might be a way.

Comment: @ Will Sawin ..the can we proceed to prove that there exist no perfect squares in sequences formed by combining $n$ and $n^k$?